# output reference-passed value in lambda from(std::function)?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, reference

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
std::function<void(int)> Foo()
{
    int v = 1;
    int r = 2;
    auto l = [v, &r](int i)
    {
        std::cout << v << " " << r << " " << i << std::endl;
    };
    return l;
}

int main()
{
    auto func = Foo();
    func(3);
    return 0;
}
```

I think will print "1 2 3", however, it is "1 -858993460 3", why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `r` is captured by reference, but it's a local variable and will be destroyed immediately after `Foo()` returns. For `func(3);` the captured reference has become invalid, and deference on it leads to [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior); anything is possible.

On the other hand, `v` is captured by value, that means it will be copied into the lambda and then works well.